# can't deploy CIS images in terraform - Unable to deploy from the Marketplace image

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to deploy a CIS Ubuntu image in Azure using Terraform, but am getting the following error:

```
│ Error: Code="VMMarketplaceInvalidInput" Message="Unable to deploy from the Marketplace image or a custom image sourced from Marketplace image. The part number in the purchase information for VM '/xxx' is not as expected. Beware that the Plan object's properties are case-sensitive. "
```

My terraform resource looks like so (changed the names for brevity):

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                              = "name"
  location                          = "East US"
  resource_group_name               = "name"
  network_interface_ids             = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]
  vm_size                           = "Standard_D8_v3"
  delete_os_disk_on_termination     = true

  storage_image_reference {
    offer     = "cis-ubuntu-linux-2004-l1"     
    publisher = "center-for-internet-security-inc" 
    sku       = "cis-ubuntu2004-l1povw-jan-2022"       
    version   = "1.1.9"
  }

  plan { 
    name      = "cis-ubuntu2004-l1"
    publisher = "center-for-internet-security-inc"
    product   = "cis-ubuntu-linux-2004-l1"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "name"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "name"
    admin_username = "username"
    admin_password = "password"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
}
```

I have accepted the terms via the CLI and get the following when querying:

```
$ az vm image terms show --offer "cis-ubuntu-linux-2004-l1" --plan "cis-ubuntu2004-l1" --publisher "center-for-internet-security-inc"
{
  "accepted": true,
  ...
```

Not sure where I am going wrong?

Comment: For version **1.1.9**  sku is **cis-ubuntu2004-l1povw** not **cis-ubuntu2004-l1povw-jan-2022**. Please change this and try it again,

Comment: Thank you, the SKU was indeed the issue, changing to "cis-ubuntu2004-l1" worked, so thank you for pointing me in the correct direction!

Comment: Glad it helped. Posting this an an answer please accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Thakn You for confirming the the issue got resolve by changing the correct sku name.Please find the same which i have tested in my enviroment.***

***You can check the List the VM image based on publishers available in the Azure Marketplace.***

```
 az vm image list --output table --all --publisher center-for-internet-security-inc.
```

[image]

In the above picture For version 1.1.9 `sku` is **`cis-ubuntu2004-l1povw`** not **`cis-ubuntu2004-l1povw-jan-2022`**.

***Refernce for url : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/image/terms?view=azure-cli-latest***